# why is the method name black bold or green in Netbeans 7.4+

Tags: netbeans

In the following Javascript code:

[image]

Why is the method autocomplete_success in bold black while the hangup and handleVisibility methods in light green?

IDE is Netbeans 7.4 with factory settings.

Comment: Here are all function keys black normal a no one green. Maybe some old settings migrated to 7.4 ?

Comment: Well, I started a new project, no migration...

Comment: I mean migration of settings in NB installation.